# ionic adjust canvas size based on orientation

Tags: canvas, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm pretty new to programming and I've been following this tutorial for making a simple drawing app in Ionic.

I followed the tutorial and was able to make it work. However when I test it on my browser using ionic serve and responsive device mode the canvas doesn't adjust after starting to draw when changing the orientation. I start drawing in portrait view and then when I flip the orientation or landscape and start drawing again I can clearly see the cut off point of the canvas.

I've attached screenshots and the code below.

**canvas-draw.html**

```
<ion-toolbar id="top-toolbar">
  <ion-buttons left>
    <button *ngFor="let colour of availableColours" icon-only ion-button (click)="changeColour(colour)">
      <ion-icon [style.color]="colour" name="brush"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-buttons right>
    <button style="border: 1px solid #cecece;" ion-button icon-only style.color="#fff" (click)="changeColour('#fff')">
      <ion-icon style="color: #fff;" name="square"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-toolbar>

<canvas #myCanvas (touchstart)="handleStart($event)" (touchmove)="handleMove($event)" (touched)="handleEnd($event)"></canvas>

<ion-toolbar id="bottom-toolbar">
  <ion-buttons left>
    <button color="dark" ion-button icon-only (click)="clearCanvas()"><ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-buttons right>
    <button color="dark" ion-button icon-only (click)="changeSize(5)"><ion-icon style="font-size: 0.25em;" name="radio-button-on"></ion-icon></button>
    <button color="dark" ion-button icon-only (click)="changeSize(10)"><ion-icon style="font-size: 0.5em;" name="radio-button-on"></ion-icon></button>
    <button color="dark" ion-button icon-only (click)="changeSize(20)"><ion-icon style="font-size: 1em;" name="radio-button-on"></ion-icon></button>
    <button color="dark" ion-button icon-only (click)="changeSize(50)"><ion-icon style="font-size: 2em;" name="radio-button-on"></ion-icon></button>
    <button color="dark" ion-button icon-only (click)="changeSize(200)"><ion-icon style="font-size: 3em;" name="radio-button-on"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-toolbar>
```

**canvas-draw.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CanvasDraw } from './canvas-draw';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CanvasDraw,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(CanvasDraw),
  ],
  exports: [
    CanvasDraw
  ]
})
export class CanvasDrawComponentModule {}
```

**canvas-draw.scss**

```
canvas-draw {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    #top-toolbar{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }
    #bottom-toolbar{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

**canvas-draw.ts**

```
import { Component,ViewChild,Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'canvas-draw',
  templateUrl: 'canvas-draw.html'
})
export class CanvasDraw {
    @ViewChild('myCanvas') canvas: any;

    canvasElement: any;
    lastX: number;
    lastY: number;

    currentColour: string = '#1abc9c';
    availableColours: any;

    brushSize: number = 10;

    constructor(public platform: Platform, public renderer: Renderer) {
        console.log('Hello CanvasDraw Component');

        this.availableColours = [
            '#1abc9c',
            '#3498db',
            '#9b59b6',
            '#e67e22',
            '#e74c3c'
        ];

    }

    ngAfterViewInit(){

        this.canvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;

        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.canvasElement, 'width', this.platform.width() + '');
        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.canvasElement, 'height', this.platform.height() + '');

    }

    changeColour(colour){
        this.currentColour = colour;
    }

    changeSize(size){
        this.brushSize = size;
    }

    handleStart(ev){

        this.lastX = ev.touches[0].pageX;
        this.lastY = ev.touches[0].pageY;
    }

    handleMove(ev){

        let ctx = this.canvasElement.getContext('2d');
        let currentX = ev.touches[0].pageX;
        let currentY = ev.touches[0].pageY;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        ctx.moveTo(this.lastX, this.lastY);
        ctx.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.currentColour;
        ctx.lineWidth = this.brushSize;
        ctx.stroke();       

        this.lastX = currentX;
        this.lastY = currentY;

    }

    handleEnd(ev){

        console.log(ev);
    }

    clearCanvas(){
        let ctx = this.canvasElement.getContext('2d');
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvasElement.width, this.canvasElement.height);   
    }

}
```

**Screenshots**

First I'm drawing in portrait view.

[image: portrait view]

Then flip the orientation and I continue drawing but you can see where the canvas is cut off.

[image: canvas is cut off]

Comment: Here is a link to the tutorial I was using: https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-drawing-application-in-ionic/

Answer (score 0):

So I added the following code to ngAfterViewInit and that was able to adjust the canvas size when the orientation changed without any cutoffs, but the drawing gets erased and so I'd still like to find out if there is a way of keeping the drawing.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", (e) => {
    this.canvasElement.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.canvasElement.height = window.innerHeight;
```